Joining multiple tables separate and later joining results
I have four tables: a, b, c, and d. My goal is to perform the following joins:

Join tables a, b, and d.
Join tables a, c, and d.

This results in two separate result sets. I then need to join these two result sets on a common column present in table a (let's call this column a_id).
Currently, I'm using correlated subqueries in the SELECT clause and joining in the WHERE clause to achieve the separate joins. However, I'm looking for the best practices or more efficient ways to achieve this.
How can I efficiently perform these joins separately and then combine the results?

Isn't that basically just (a join b on ... join d) join (c join d on ...) on a.something = something else?

A [mcve] is a great start when asking for SQL assistance.

It depends on the join conditions (and type), distribution of values of join columns, the volume of data, indices on those, included columns and your select list, resources available to the server, etc; you haven't given much information.

Please provide sample data and desired results.

Try using CTEs , create two CTEs and then join them as you would two tables on column from Table A.
